# Django CORS headers whitelist doesn't work

Tags: python, django, header, cors

I'm working on an existing code base which consists of a Django backend and a ReactJS frontend.
Everything is dockerized so I'm running the backend on `localhost:8001` and the frontend on `localhost:3000`.

Because I got CORS errors in the browser, I added [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) to Django. When I add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` however, I get an error saying

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://127.0.0.1:8001/devices/’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

So then I added the following settings:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http//:127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http//:127.0.0.1:8001',
)
```

But than I get an error saying

> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Why is the whitelist not working? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Typo: The settings shown in the question have values starting with `http//:` — but they should instead start with `http://`.

Answer (score 2):

Install any cross origin browser extension in Your browser when you run front end code locally,it will helpful.

and change the whitelist url as below (//: should be ://):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
'http://127.0.0.1:8001',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`, this will set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and as the error suggests while allowing all the domains for cross-origin requests, you can't pass `credentials` flag with the request. So if you want to keep the header as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, the easiest fix would be to not use the `credentials` flag while sending the CORS request from the frontend.

If you want to allow only a certain domains (which is preferable), you need to find the valid domains first. Remember these domains are the originating domains from where requests are coming to Django. You can find them by looking at [`request.META.REMOTE_HOST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). `request.META` is the environment seen and passed on by WSGI, and if you have some proxies in between that will give you the last host in the proxy chain.

If you have a web server that talks WSGI e.g. `nginx`, it will pass on the `REMOTE_HOST` to your Django application or to any intermediate WSGI server you have (e.g. `uWSGI`/`gunicorn`) and they will in turn pass that to your app.

---

Also, in your settings, the URLs in `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` are in wrong format; the separator between scheme and netloc is `://`,  not `//:` e.g.:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
```